# R - read.csv add rows when loading the dataset

Tags: r, csv

I'm trying to read a .csv in R. Some rows of one column have text with a komma, within double quotes: *"example, another example"* 
But R alters the rows (it adds rows) when I try to read it like this:

```
steekproef <- read.csv('steekproef.csv', header = T, quote = "", sep = ',')
```

This one doesn't work either when I did a search on the internet:

```
steekproef <- read.csv('steekproef.csv', header = T, quote = "\"", sep = ',')
```

This is the error message:

```
steekproef <- read.csv("steekproef.csv", header = T, sep =",", quote ="\"")

comes with error:

Warning message:
In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
EOF within quoted string

Gives data.frame:      1391160 obs. of  29 variables


str(steekproef) gives no error but a

'data.frame':  3103620 obs. of  29 variables:


The dataset has 29 columns and 3019438 rows
```

Comment: I can't replicate your error, probably I have inputed the dummy csv file in a different format...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the problem is caused be the "example, another example":

I created a testfile in Excel and saved it as .csv. It looks like this in Notepad++:

```
test,num
"example, another example",1
"example, another example",2
example,3
example,4
```

I could import it without problems using

`steekproef<- read.csv('steekproef.csv', header = T, sep = ',')`

or `steekproef <- read.csv('steekproef.csv', header = T, quote = "\"", sep = ',')`

Your first try: `steekproef <- read.csv('steekproef.csv', header = T, quote = "", sep = ',')` gave me the `Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,: duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed`